# read data from last consummed offset in kafka using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am using confluent python kafka library to consume messages from kafka.
Is there a way to start consuming messages from the last consumed one ?
Say that I have 10 messages in a topic:
 * I consume those 10 messages
After a while I have a couple more message written to that topic.
I would like to consume those messages, but first hand skip over those first 10 messages and so on.
Is it possible ?

I've tried setting 'auto.offset.reset' to 'largest', but that will make me consume from that point on. It will not consume 'unread' messages.

Meaning, if I write 10 messages in a topic and then try to consume them with that setting activated, it will listen only for incoming (new) messages.

This is the function for polling messages:

```
In [50]: def get_messages(topics=None):
...:     try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
...:         c = Consumer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'xyz_group', 'default.topic.config': {'enable.auto.commit': 'true'}})
...:         if topics is not None:
...:             c.subscribe(topics)
...:     except KafkaException as e:
...:         print('We got an exception: {}'.format(e))
...:     else:
...:         running = True
...:         while running:
...:             msg = c.poll()
...:             if not msg.error():
...:                 msg_payload = msg.value().decode('utf-8')
...:                 print('Received: {}'.format(msg_payload))
...:                 msg_data = json.loads(msg_payload)
...:                 for k, v in msg_data.iteritems():
...:                     if k == 'signal' and v == 'stop':
...:                         running = False 
...:                         #raise SystemExit('we got stop signal !')
...:                     else:                         
...:                         print('continue listening ...')
...:             elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
...:                 print(msg.error())     
...:                 running = False                                  
...:     finally:             
...:         c.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the default behaviour, namely of auto commit being enabled (`enable.auto.commit=true`).
The last consumed message's offset will be committed at frequent intervals (`auto.commit.interval.ms`).

When properly shutting down the consumer (by calling `close()`) it will commit its final offsets.
Upon restarting the client it will pick up from where it left off and consume messages newer than the last consumed one.

Comment: t is strange. It worked once, and then I get the same behaviour. I thought that by default you get 'auto.offset.reset' set to 'largest'.

Comment: I am producing beforehand, using Producer(), some data into a topic. Then I am trying to consume that topic, using Consumer(), but except using 'auto.offset.reset set to 'true', I can't get the data. Some times it works. It's quite strange.

Comment: I think the problemwas related to a version of zookeeper that comes bundled with kafka confluent version.

Comment: auto.offset.reset=true is not valid config, it should `beginning`, `end` or `error`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'earliest' or 'small' | 'largest' or 'latest'. Ok, noted.